# Which conditions make an associative algebra a matrix algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

If I have an algebra over a field, which additional conditions would make this algebra uniquely the matrix algebra?

I'm already assuming that I have an $n^2$ dimensional vector-space equipped with an associative bilinear product. I think this still allows for more spaces than just matrices?

Which additional conditions would fix this to be the matrix algebra over the field?

Comment: Indeed, an $n^2$-dimensional algebra need not be isomorphic to a matrix algebra, take $T_n(F) \times T_{n-1}(F)$. Is this for computation? You can use that $M_n$ is central simple. The center is obtained by solving a linear system: if an element commutes with every basis element, it is central. The radical is more tricky, Section 2 of the paper L. Ronyai, ["Computing the structure of finite algebras"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82517692.pdf) might be of help for some fields.

Comment: But then, of course, you still need to distinguish algebras such as $\Bbb H$ and $M_2(\Bbb R)$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which kind of conditions you are expecting, but we can characterize matrix algebras in terms of center and ideals.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional associative $F$-algebra. We say that $A$ is

- central if  the center is $F.1_A$
- simple if  the only two-sided ideals of $A$ are $(0)$ and $A$.

Then $M_n(F)$ is central simple. Moreover, $M_n(F)$ has a left ideal of dimension $n$, that is  for example the set of matrices whose  first $n-1$ columns are zero.

One may show that the dimension of a central simple  $F$-algebra is a square. Hence the following result makes sense.

**Thm.** Let $A$ be a finite dimensional associative $F$-algebra. Then $A$ is isomorphic to a matrix $F$-algebra if anf only if $A$ is central, simple and has a left ideal of dimension $n=\sqrt{\dim_F(A)}$.
In this case, we get $A\simeq M_n(F)$.

**Proof.** If $I$ is a left ideal of dimension $n=\sqrt{\dim_F(A)}$,

then for all $a\in A$, the map $\ell_a: x\in I\mapsto ax\in I$ is $F$-linear, since $F.1_A\subset Z(A)$ (which is true for any associative unital $F$-algebra. Centrality is not required).

We then have a map $a\in A \mapsto \ell_a\in End_F(I)$, which happens to be a  morphism of $F$-algebras (once again, this just uses $F.1_A\subset Z(A)$). Since $A$ is simple, its kernel is trivial, and thus this map is injective. By comparing dimensions, we see that this is an isomorphism. Since $I$ jhas dimension $n$, we get $A\simeq End_F(I)\simeq M_n(F)$.

**Remark.** We used centrality to justify that the dimension of $A$ is a square. Examining the proof above shows that we also have the following result. (Centrality then becomes a corollary)

**Thm.** Let $A$ be an associative $F$-algebra of dimension $n^2$. Then $A$ is isomorphic to $M_n(F)$ if and only if $A$ is simple and has a left ideal of dimension $n$.

Comment: wow, I didn't expect this question to have an answer this straightforward. Awesome.

Comment: I'm only slightly familiar with these concepts, but I think it's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks!! Any algebra book you could recommend which is concise, but yet explores these topics?

Comment: @GreginGre How many conditions can I drop and still get the matrix algebra uniquely? Can I just say my algebra has an associative bilinear product and it is simple to fix matrix algebra? Do I have to require that a left ideal exists? Or do all simple algebras necessarily have a left ideal of some dimension $n$ and must be of dimension $n^2$?

Comment: You cannot drop any of these, i am afraid. If you forget the condition about the left ideal, then you have plenty of possibilities, unless $F$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @GreginGre Thanks! Maybe some last questions. I'm happy to assume that the field are complex numbers. Can I then drop conditions? Therefore are all simple algebras based on the complex field automatically the matrix algebra (with some unspecified dimension of the ideal).
I suppose all natural numbers are allowed for the dimension? Can you think of some "natural" algebraic restriction I could add to force the dimension of the ideal to be $2^n$? I'm asking because those would correspond to Clifford algebras.

Comment: **Central** simple $\mathbb{C}$-algebras are automatically matrix algebras. You do not need anymore condition about the existence of left ideals of some speficic dimension.

Left and right ideals of $M_m(F)$ are well-known for any field $F$. I do not want to describe them here, but I can at least tell you that the dimension on a left/right ideal of $M_n(F)$ is a multiple of $n$...